# converting a grayscale image to black and white image in c#

Tags: c#

I have written some c# code converting my rgb image to grayscale and I would like to convert the grayscale to only 2 colors, black and while.
Can you help?

**Code:-**

```
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(file);
 int width = bmp.Width;
 int height = bmp.Height;
 int[] arr = new int[225];
 int i = 0;
 Color p;

 //Grayscale
 for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
 {
     for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
     {
         p = bmp.GetPixel(x,y);
         int a = p.A;
         int r = p.R;
         int g = p.G;
         int b = p.B;
         int avg = (r+g+b)/3;
         bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, avg ,avg, avg));
     }
 }
 pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: Based on what criteria??

Comment: take your gray get and set the pixel white if it exceeds some limit and black otherwise ... but it will most likely look like s*** ;)

Comment: Your grayscale conversion code is borken, the human eye is very sensitive to green, not so sensitive to red, sucks at blue.  Has a lot to do with the colors of things you can eat.  Use 0.21 * r + 0.71 * g + 0.07 * b.  Clipping to black or white simply takes comparing to 0.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've changed your code a little. So light gray pixels become pure white and dark gray pixels become pure black.

```
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(file);
 int width = bmp.Width;
 int height = bmp.Height;
 int[] arr = new int[225];
 int i = 0;
 Color p;

 //Grayscale
 for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
 {
     for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
     {
         p = bmp.GetPixel(x,y);
         int a = p.A;
         int r = p.R;
         int g = p.G;
         int b = p.B;
         int avg = (r+g+b)/3;
         avg = avg < 128 ? 0 : 255;     // Converting gray pixels to either pure black or pure white
         bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, avg ,avg, avg));
     }
 }
 pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: Thank you Farzan Hajain. This works. Thanks to you'll for the suggestions and help

Comment: @jeanthierry ensure to mark one of the given answers as accepted if one of them solved your problem, welcome to SO but read the rules, thanks.

Comment: Please use `int avg = (int)(0.2989*r + 0.5870*g + 0.1140*b)/3;` as the `int avg = (r+g+b)/3;` is so very wrong!

Answer (score 6):

You should stop using `GetPixel` method on any scenario.

I'm an VB.Net guy, I've write this approach which you can convert the image to black and white.

First I apply the gray matrix then with the `SetThreshold` method I set the threshold that separates black from white.

```
''' <summary>
''' Transforms an image to black and white.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="img">The image.</param>
''' <returns>The black and white image.</returns>
Public Shared Function GetBlackAndWhiteImage(ByVal img As Image) As Image

    Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height)

    Dim grayMatrix As New System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix(
        {
            New Single() {0.299F, 0.299F, 0.299F, 0, 0},
            New Single() {0.587F, 0.587F, 0.587F, 0, 0},
            New Single() {0.114F, 0.114F, 0.114F, 0, 0},
            New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            New Single() {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
        })

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

        Using ia As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes = New System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes()

            ia.SetColorMatrix(grayMatrix)
            ia.SetThreshold(0.5)

            g.DrawImage(img, New Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height,
                                             GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia)

        End Using

    End Using

    Return bmp

End Function
```

**Online translation to C#:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Transforms an image to black and white.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="img">The image.</param>
/// <returns>The black and white image.</returns>
public static Image GetBlackAndWhiteImage(Image img)
{

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix grayMatrix  = new ColorMatrix(
        new float[][] {
            new float[] { 0.299f, 0.299f, 0.299f, 0, 0  },
            new float[] { 0.587f, 0.587f, 0.587f, 0, 0  },
            new float[] { 0.114f, 0.114f, 0.114f, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
        }););

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {

    using (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes ia = new System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes()) {

        ia.SetColorMatrix(grayMatrix);
        ia.SetThreshold(0.5);

        g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);

    }

}

return bmp;

}

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//=======================================================
```

Comment: @jeanthierry good to help you, but you need to learn that pixel by pixel manipulation (`For... Bitmap.GetPixel`) is x100 times slower than what I shown you.